# Checking if user is authenticated always results in true

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to check when a user is authenticated and I am always getting that the user is authenticated. Here is my code:

```
 if( User.Identity.IsAuthenticated )
 {
     addProfiledata();
 }
```

This condition always is true even if I log in and log out.

How can I correct this?

Comment: did you using **FormsAuthentication.Signout()** to logout from application.

Comment: where do you set that he is no longer authenticated ?

Comment: I have used a LoginControl I did asume it does use it automaticly I will try it

Comment: what kind of authentication are you using, forms or windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have defined users role then it should be handled, you are using LoginControl and i guess you are handling sing out sing in with other login controls like loginview and hope you are assigning the user roles to it. if this is a case you can use LoginUser_LoggedIn event

```
   // suppose if you are willing to redirect a user according to his/her role
protected void LoginUser_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))
            {
                // if user in role and authenticated 
                if (Roles.IsUserInRole(LoginUser.UserName, "Developers"))
                {
                    // add session and redirect to particular page
                    Session.Add("developer", "Developers");
                    Response.Redirect("../Developers/devAccess.aspx");
```

```
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated) {

  //put code for Authenticated user 

}
```

Or alternately

```
if(User.IsInRole("rolename")) {

  //put code for Authenticated user 

}
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: I have tryed HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated it still does now work the method inside still gets executed